# UTC representation of midnight on the UTC day that was in progress 24 hours ago in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, pytz

I want to format timestamp to day -1 but require a format
I am getting day-1 exactly minus 24 hrs but I need from midnight onwards

```py
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import pytz
partdate=datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
# print(partdate)

# import pytz

tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
# print(tzinfo)


x=(datetime.now() + timedelta(days=-1))  # Here
tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
pardate1=tzinfo.localize(datetime.now()+timedelta(days=-1),is_dst=None)
print(pardate1)
#print('x----->',x)
#print('timevalue',tzinfo)


# yesterday = datetime.today() - timedelta(days = 1 )
# print(yesterday)
```

*output is 2022-08-13 20:39:26.232974-04:00*

But required output is 2022-08-13T00:00:000Z

[image: datetime error]

Comment: The `Z` at the end of your required output indicates that you *also* want to convert from EDT to UTC.  Is that correct?   Can the problem be stated as "a UTC representation of midnight on the UTC day that was in progress 24 hours ago?"

Comment: yes it should be EDT to UTC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want date/time now in a certain time zone, subtract one day, then convert to UTC, then 'floor' that date/time to midnight.

Here's a step-by-step example how you can do that. Note that I use `zoneinfo` since `pytz` is deprecated and time zone name "America/New_York" as "US/Eastern" is obsolte as well.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

now = datetime.now(ZoneInfo("America/New_York"))

daybefore = now - timedelta(days=1)

daybefore_UTC = daybefore.astimezone(ZoneInfo("UTC"))

daybefore_UTC_midnight = daybefore_UTC.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

print(now)
print(daybefore_UTC_midnight)
# 2022-08-15 03:38:42.006215-04:00
# 2022-08-14 00:00:00+00:00
```

Comment: have same requirement in scala ? any suggestions

Comment: @Db8 you mean the programming language? Sorry, zero expertise with that one...